# Android - Check which class I came from

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent

So I want to check which class I came from in another class. For example, I have class A, B, C. Now, in B there is an intent which opens class A. And in C, there is an intent that opens class A. But, depending on which class I came from, I will may have to do some different methods for that specific class. OK, so I'll give you mine. I have a Themes.class, and a Soft key.class. Both will open up a Bmod.class. Now, almost both classes will do the same thing. The only difference is, when I download a file, the Output Stream will have a different directory. So, I went ahead and tried some code. Here is what I tried:

```
                            //Download the file
            Object obj = null;
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = null;
            if(obj instanceof Themes){
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/plasma/battery/batterymod.zip");
            }if(obj instanceof Softkeys){
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/plasma/softkeys/softkeys.zip");
            }
```

Now, when I run the app, nothing downloads. I'm assuming I did something wrong, and so the app doesn't know what the output stream is. So, my question is as the title states: How do I properly check in one class which class I previously came from. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How do I properly check in one class which class I previously came from
```

I think you are navigating between the activities so you can get the top activity like this

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.
    getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

it uses the permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'll try it. So, would I use something like.     if(classname != null){                                       //code

Comment: This didn't work either, unless I did it wrong. Could you maybe edit your post with an example of how to use it in my case(for the file output stream)?

Answer (score 2):

When you call startActivity(//intent activity A), just put and extra string intent.putExtra("From", "classB" // or "classC"). In the onCreate method of A call getIntent().getStringExtra("From", "") and depend on what you get do whatever you want.

Comment: I already did this so I can determine which file to download. I have at least 50 put extras for each class, and I don't want to say if(extra1 != null || extra2 != null || extra3 != null, ect.)

Comment: Why do you need 50 extras. If these are the name of the files to download then you can just use putStringArrayExtra

Comment: I have a lot of different things going on for each button that was clicked than just downloading. Sorry. I should've been more clear.